# NullPointerException on asynctask with adapter

Tags: android-asynctask, adapter

I am using asy task with adapter and get  this error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

the problem line is

```
 listAdapter = new listAdpterRss(this.context, R.layout.listitems,RssArrays,RssArrays.rtl);
```

my asy task looks like that

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
        ListView lv = getListView();
    //  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listAdapter = new listAdpterRss(this.context, R.layout.listitems,RssArrays,RssArrays.rtl);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter); // on test
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RssItem.this,openRssItem.WebActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", RssArrays.PodcastURL[position].toString());

                startActivity(intent);
                //new splash(ListRss.this,mHandler,listValue.get(position).toString()).execute();
            } 

        });
```

Comment: the debug exception is before that I get the contractor of   listAdapterRss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting adapter later and might be using in you doInBackground method . Thats why it is showing nullPointer.
Please put all of these onPreExecute():

ListView lv = getListView();
    //  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listAdapter = new listAdpterRss(this.context, R.layout.listitems,RssArrays,RssArrays.rtl);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);

And then try your code.